# sc stop winDefend/deleting MpCmdRun.exe access denied

Tags: windows, powershell, batch, cmd.exe, windows-server-2019

I am trying to stop windows defender service as an administrator but I am getting access denied error. The intention is to remove "MpCmdRun.exe" file after stopping service. I tried changing the ownership of "C:\Program Files\Windows Defender" folder to administrator for deleting the file but all in vain. I am getting access denied even when deleting that file.

The OS is Windows Server 2019

Comment: Is tamper protection enabled? If so, you need to disable it first: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/prevent-changes-to-security-settings-with-tamper-protection-31d51aaa-645d-408e-6ce7-8d7f8e593f87#:~:text=In%20the%20search%20box%20on,setting%20to%20On%20or%20Off.

Comment: @Cpt.Whale I am using Windows server 2019 and I don't see tamper related settings

Comment: On windows server, use powershell `Get-MpComputerStatus` and check for `IsTamperProtected` or `RealTimeProtectionEnabled` as described here: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/security/defender-endpoint/prevent-changes-to-security-settings-with-tamper-protection?view=o365-worldwide#use-powershell-to-determine-whether-tamper-protection-and-real-time-protection-are-turned-on

Comment: Since it looks like you're trying to permanently remove it on server 2019, you probably want to uninstall the feature rather than delete the cli tool. For example: `Uninstall-WindowsFeature -Name Windows-Defender`

Comment: Or install another anti-malware suite. Running without protection is generally a *very* bad idea, especially for a server. Unless you're making a honeypot...

Comment: I don't want to uninstall WD. Just want to delete MpCmdRun.exe file to prevent a kind of vulnerability which was reported by vulnerability scanner tool.

Comment: It has realtime protection enabled but even after disabling it neither I am not able to stop the service or delete the file

Comment: @DrMoishePippik that is not the intention here. We don't want to install any new AV softwares.

Comment: I am new to Windows  OS so please excuse if I ask any silly questions

Comment: @user3847894 - Except removing `MpCmdRun.exe` from your system effectively kills Windows Defender.  Are you positive that this vulnerability scanner tool's results are accurate?

Comment: @user3847894 any vulnerability for windows defender or the mpcmdrun tool is just going to be related to, and fixed by, windows updates. For example: CVE-2020-1163 https://msrc.microsoft.com/update-guide/vulnerability/CVE-2020-1163

Answer (score 0):

MpCmdRun.exe is an [intrinsic part of Windows Defender](https://helpdeskgeek.com/windows-10/what-is-mpcmdrun-exe-and-how-to-use-it/). Since you state you, "don't want to uninstall WD. Just want to delete MpCmdRun.exe..." that is antithetical to your purpose.

My guess is that the application scanning your system(s) for "vulnerabilities" is designed to motivate you to install that company's *own* security suite to *replace* Windows Defender.

Again, you likely require *some* anti-malware application, and if your choice is Windws Defender, you need MpCmdRun.exe.

Comment: The simplest way to "disable" Windows Defender is to use some other security suite, the suite will be detected by Windows Defender, and will disable it's active scanning components. While it's possible to "disable" Windows Defender in other ways, you are effectively breaking it, so you will be at the mercy at numerous protection mechanics to prevent malicious software from doing exactly that.

Comment: On Windows Server 2019, the suggested resolution to your problem, is indeed [`Uninstall-WindowsFeature -Name Windows-Defender`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/security/defender-endpoint/microsoft-defender-antivirus-on-windows-server?view=o365-worldwide).  I suppose a workaround would be to run `Set-MpPreference -DisableRealtimeMonitoring $true` to effectively disable it.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows 7 and above, you can use the pre-boot Windows Command Prompt in Recovery Console to delete files before Windows has loaded.

Therefore, should you wish to remove the Windows Defender files, you can remove them here without the "access denied" pop-ups.